# Delete words from given files with sed

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

I have this assignment to solve:

"Write a shell script that continuously reads words from the keyboard and 
deletes them from all the files given in the command line."

I've tried to solve it, here's my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter words"
while (true)

do
        read wrd
        if [ "$wrd" != "exit" ]
        then
                for i in $#
                do
                        sed -i -e 's/$wrd//g' $i
                done
        else
        break
        fi
done
```

This is the error that I receive after introducing the command: `./h84a.sh fisier1.txt`

```
Enter words
suc
sed: can't read 1: No such file or directory
```

Sorry if I'm not very specific, it's my first time posting in here. I'm working in a terminal on Linux Mint which is installed on another partition of my PC. Please help me with my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Use `for i in "$@"` in place of `for i in $#`.  `$#` is the number of arguments to the script (apparently 1), but `"$@"` is the list of arguments — presumably file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your script quite a lot:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter words"

while read -r wrd
do
    [ "$wrd" = exit ] && break
    sed -i "s/$wrd//g" "$@"
done
```

Some key changes:

- The double quotes around the sed command are essential, as shell variables are not expanded within single quotes
- Instead of using a loop, it is possible to pass all of the file names to sed at once, using `"$@"`
- [`read -r` is almost always what you want to use](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r)

I would suggest that you take care with in-place editing using the `-i` switch. In some versions of sed, you can specify the suffix of a backup file like `-i.bak`, so the original file is not lost.

In case you're not familiar with the syntax `[ "$wrd" = exit ] && break`, it is functionally equivalent to:

```
if [ "$wrd" = exit ]
then break
fi
```

Comment: Haha, it worked! Thanks a lot. I think the main problems in my solution were the use of $# instead of $@ and the lack of double quotes around the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

`$#` expands to the number of arguments (so 1 in this case)

You probably meant to use `$*` or `"$@"`

Comment: I made the change, now no error shows up but it doesn't change the file whatsoever.

Comment: Try running your shell script with -x to see what steps it takes, that may help you figure out what went wrong

Comment: Almost invariably using `"$@"` is correct; very seldom is either `$*` or `"$*"` or `$@` (without double quotes) the correct thing to use.  Occasionally, it is reasonable to use, for example, `echo "Files: $*"` which has `$*` inside double quotes.  But otherwise, it is more usually a bug than correct.